# Sending "thank you" letter to the hiring manager

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process

I applied to a position and I was scheduled to conduct a phone interview with two individuals - the manager and someone who works for the manager. But when I received the call, the individual who works for the manager told me that the manager had to take an unexpected phone call and that he would be conducting the phone interview.

I have started to prepare my "thank you" letter. I will be sending it to the person who I spoke with and the assistant to the manager who set up the interview. But I don't know if I should also send a "thank you" letter to the manager for preparing to speak with me, although he could not.

So I was wondering: Should I send a "thank you" email to the hiring manager for considering to speak with me? Or is there some thing else that I could/should do to show my gratitude?

Thanks.

Comment: @JimG. I'm curious. Did you read the title of this question and assume that its a duplicate of the one you thought it was of?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @user65422, I didn't read just the title, I read the whole question and then I read the one JimG suggested and the answers. It looks like a duplicate to me, sorry.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Well perhaps you'd be kind enough to share which answer that you thought answered my question. Where in other question does it say whether an individual should write a **thank you** letter to someone you never met or spoke to?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are still interested in the position, then I think you should email the manager, but not to say "thank you" for preparing to speak with you.

Instead, you should email him/her and say that you are sorry that you didn't get a chance to talk to him/her during the phone interview.  Express your interest in the position, and make an offer to set up another phone interview with him.

As the hiring manager, he/she would surely like to get to know a person who will potentially join his/her team.  Obviously he/she will find out about you by speaking to the person who conducted the phone interview, but nothing beats talking to you directly.  I think offering to speak with him/her in another phone interview will impress him/her with your initiative and indicate that you really are interested in the position.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?